# A better way of left padding a string with zeroes

Tags: java, string

This is how I left pad a string with zeroes:

```
String.format("%16s", cardTypeString.trim()).replace(' ', '0');
```

Is there a better way to do this? I don't like the `.replace(' ', '0')` part.

Answer (score 6):

You may use StringUtils from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
StringUtils.leftPad(cardTypeString, 16, '0');
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement you own `PadLeft`:

```
public static String padLeft(String value, int width, char pad) {
    if (value.length() >= width)
        return value;
    char[] buf = new char[width];
    int padLen = width - value.length();
    Arrays.fill(buf, 0, padLen, pad);
    value.getChars(0, value.length(), buf, padLen);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/iANoZ6).

Answer (score 3):

```
// Pad with zeros and a width of 10 chars.
String.format("%1$010d", 245)
```

for more details see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Sorry. My fault. This will only work for int, not for String!